# use hangfire as windows service by topshelf (.net core 2.2)

Tags: c#, hangfire, topshelf

I am trying to use **hangfire** as windows service by using **Topshelf** in console **app .net core 2.2** . I just want to **load hangfire dashboard**, not adding any job or anything else.

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using Topshelf;

namespace HangfireAsService
{
 class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  HostFactory.Run(config =>
  {
    config.Service<Bootstrap>(service =>
    {
      service.ConstructUsing(s => new Bootstrap());
      service.WhenStarted(s => s.Start());
      service.WhenStopped(s => s.Stop());
    });
    config.RunAsLocalSystem();
    config.SetDescription("Hangfire as windows Service for DataCrawling Project");
    config.SetDisplayName("Hangfire Service Custom");
   });
  }
 }
}
```

**Bootstrap.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;

namespace HangfireAsService
{
  public class Bootstrap
{
private IDisposable _host;


public void Start()
{
  var options = new StartOptions { Port = 8999 };
  _host = WebApp.Start<Startup>(options);
  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine("Hangfire has started");
  Console.WriteLine("Dashboard is available at http://localhost:8999/hangfire");
  Console.WriteLine();
}

public void Stop()
{
  _host.Dispose();
}
}
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using Hangfire;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;


namespace HangfireAsService
{
 public class Startup
 {
  public void Configuration(IApplicationBuilder appBuilder)
 {
  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
    .UseSqlServerStorage("Server=111.111.11.1\\INS2017; Database=Hangfire; user=sa; 
    password=;");
  appBuilder.UseHangfireDashboard();
  appBuilder.UseHangfireServer();

  }
 }
}
```

As you can see, I created 2 classes for my **self-host owin** and after reviewing **the event viewer** I got the error displayed below:

> The description for Event ID 0 from source HangfireAsService cannot be
>   found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on
>   your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install
>   or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> Service cannot be started. System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Utilities.SettingsLoader.FromConfigImplementation..ctor()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Utilities.SettingsLoader.<>c.b__1_0()
>   at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T&
>   target, Func`1 valueFactory)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Utilities.SettingsLoader.LoadFromConfig(IDictionary`2
>   settings)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.StartContext..ctor(StartOptions options)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.DirectHostingStarter.Start(StartOptions
>   options)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.HostingStarter.Start(StartOptions
>   options)    at HangfireAsService.Bootstrap.Start() in
>   C:\MyWorkSpace\Data
>   Crawling\dataCrawlingConsole\HangfireAsService\Bootstrap.cs:line 17
>   at HangfireAsService.Program.<>c.b__0_3(Bootstrap s) in
>   C:\MyWorkSpace\Data
>   Crawling\dataCrawlingConsole\HangfireAsService\Program.cs:line 15
>   at
>   Topshelf.ServiceConfiguratorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`1.<WhenStarted>b__0(T
>   service, HostControl control)    at
>   Topshelf.Builders.DelegateServiceBuilder`1.DelegateServiceHandle.Start(HostControl
>   hostControl)    at
>   Topshelf.Runtime.Windows.WindowsServiceHost.OnStart(String[] args)
>   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object
>   state)

The message resource is present, but the message was not found in the message table.

Comment: Please format your code samples. Badly formatted code is lazy and sends a message that the question is not worth answering.

Comment: if you mean error section, that is exactly same thing event viewer shows, but about 3 section code  I think its clear to read.

Comment: No, I mean the code samples. It's clear to read for you because you wrote this code. If you are expecting people to help you you should be making your question as easy for them to read as possible. I upvoted your question because I think it's a valuable question, but if you want more people to help you then reformat your code.

Answer (score 2):

i used same code inside .net framework instead of .net core and work perfectly.after a test something else i notice this problem because of OWIN happened so after i removed it and use using .net core self-host instead of OWIN everything work perfectly.
below link  will help you a lot.

https://medium.com/@tocalai/create-windows-service-using-net-core-console-application-dc2f278bbe42